# Doctrine2, PersistentCollection and JMS Serializer

Tags: json, doctrine-orm, jmsserializerbundle

I have an Entity with a oneToMany relationship, I can get the associated items using;

```
$this->getQueuedItems()
```

This returns *Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection* object, I am then passing this to [JMS Serializer](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle#usage) like so;

```
$serializer = $container->get('serializer');
$json = $serializer->serialize($this->getQueuedItems(), 'json');
```

But outputting `$json` using `var_dump()` results in;

> string(2) "[]"

Which is wrong. There is data there, because if I do a `foreach()` over `$this->getQueuedItems()` I get data.

How can I use JMS Serializer to serialise *Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection* into JSON?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PersistentCollection object is an Iterator Aggregate and not an array. The distinction is that an Iterator is an object that can be iterated over and so may or may not contain the data required for serializing to an array at any one time.

To serialize the Collection as JSON, try the following:

```
$serializer = $container->get('serializer');
$arr        = $this->getQueuedItems()->toArray();
$json       = $serializer->serialize($arr, 'json');
```

If you're not too fussed about the keys, you could also use `getValues`, rather than `toArray`.

Comment: Thanks @hobnob, I must have gotten around this some other way by now, but thanks for the input.

Comment: @JakeN please if you can, post how you solved it. in one2many serialization given answer isn't helpful.

Comment: Looking over my code now, I do not even use `toArray`. You might want to try this bundle as it does relationships for you https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle

Comment: @Oshanz this worked for me. I have a Location entity that has an images property that's a one-to-many, and I can just call `toArray()` on it. Did you try making both entities implement `JsonSerializable`?